# Rasterizing Paths data from Photoshop file

Tags: photoshop, vector-graphics, rasterizing

I was able to read the paths data from a Photoshop file.[Photoshop File Format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml).  The curves bezier curves. I want to convert this data into pixel format. How do i do this?.

Comment: Try using something like Cairo.
Or ask a more specific question like "I want to render bezier curves in C/C++/Web/iOS/Android etc." Your available options might not be compatible between different platforms and languages. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read thouroughly the documentation given [On the Adobe's Website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/). I separated the data as 26 byte records.

Let's say one of the record is as follows

```
0 0 | 0 12 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The first two bytes of each record is a selector to indicate what kind of path it is. 0 0 indicates that it is a **Closed subpath length record.**

The next 8 Bytes tell us the control point for the Bezier segment **preceding the knot**. Now this can again be split into two components X and Y
the *first 4 bytes are the vertical components.*

```
0 12 0 0
```

I converted 12 0 0 to binary format and add them and them convert to decimal

```
00001100 + 00000000 + 00000000  = 00001100
```

and then converted the result back to decimal. Which gave me Y co-ordinate.

where 0 indicates that the position is in the positive range(Signed magnitude form).

The next 8 bytes indicate the the anchor point for the knot, and the last 8 bytes the control point for the Bezier segment leaving the knot. The X and Y Components can be found in a similar manner.

I had this data exported to a svg file and then ran a rasterizer to convert the point data to pixel data.

If someone comes across this post I Hope this helps. :)